# Arrange the numbers by subtracting

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a java problem that I don't know how to solve the program is :

two number must got from user n,k.

I need to find a permuation of numbers from 1 to N such that the difference between two items >=k for example :

we get the numbers    (n = 5 and k = 2 )

and the answer must be 1,4,2,5,3 :

and for (n=2 and k = 2) there is not answer because the difference between 1 and two is 1(1,2 or 2,1).

I hope you understand what I want.

and I write some codes that are wrong:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = user_input.nextInt();
    int k = user_input.nextInt();
    int a ;
if (n%2==0) a = (n-2)/2; else a = (n-1)/2 ;  

if (k!=a) {System.out.println("Impossible"); return;}

int h = k+1;
int value = 0;
int t = 1;
boolean b = true;
String res = "1 ";
    while (value<n-1) {            
        value++;
        if (b){
            t = t + h;
            res = res + t + " ";
            b = false;
        }else {
            t = t-k;
            res = res + t + " ";
            b = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(res);


}
```

Comment: is this a homework?

Comment: @xxlali why?its easy??

Comment: Actually, the definition of your task is not clear. What is "a order of number"? What about n? Why is there no answer for n=2,k=2?

Comment: As far as i understand, u need to find a permuation of numbers from 1 to N such that the difference between two items >=k. @erfan.sajjadie am i correct?

Comment: what do you want to do you are not clear about your code

Comment: "we have to print a order of numbers that thier difference be k or more"
difference between which two numbers ? Please be more clear.

Comment: @Aditya K yes you are correct.

Comment: Hacker's earth / Hacker's rank / Codechef?

Comment: OK. One approach to do this is to create a program that generates permutations recursively. Can you do that? And then, change that program so that it checks at each step that the difference between the current number and the first number in the sub-permutation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static  void calculationMethod(int n, int k) {
        if(n<2 || n/2 < k) {
            System.out.println("Impossible");
            return;
        }
        else {
            int i = (int)Math.ceil(n/2.0);
            int j = n;
            int start = i;
            boolean flag = true;
            while(i>=1 || j>start) {
                if(flag) {
                   System.out.print(i + " " );
                   i--;
                   flag = false;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(j + " " );
                    j--;
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


     public static void main(String []args){
        calculationMethod(7,3);
     }
}
```

The idea is to divide your range(n) in half. If k>n/2 then it is not possible to construct any such sequence.

If that is not the case, then have 2 pointers one at the middle of your range and one at the end of the range. and print them alternatively decrementing both pointers until u reach the beginning.

Feel free to improve the code.

Comment: your code was completely true
thanks alot for your answer.
your solution was awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void calculationMethod(int n, int k) {
    ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int a = i;
            int b = i + 2;
            if (!intList.contains(a) && a<=n) {
                intList.add(a);
            }
            if (!intList.contains(b) && b<=n) {
                intList.add(b);
            }
    }
    String mValues= TextUtils.join(",",intList);
    Log.i("values", mValues);
}
```

Comment: Haven't looked over your solution, dunno if it works, but in any case, you really really want to write an explanation of your code. The problem is not a trivial one, so it's quite important to understand why an algorithm works. Wouldn't upvote an answer, even if it is correct, as long as it misses such an explanation.